# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'Gana' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

` try {
const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
const storageRef = ref(storage,displayName);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

```
  uploadTask.on((error) => {setErr(true)},() => {
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)

      .then(async (downloadURL) => {
        await updateProfile(response.user,{displayName,photoURL:downloadURL});
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", response.user.uid), {uid:response.user.uid, displayName, email, photoURL:downloadURL});
      });
    }
  );  

} catch (err) {
  setErr(true);
}`
```

I am able to see my data on the authentication, storage, and cloud Firestore, when I am registering on the registration page but still am I getting an error:

Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'Gana' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)